# iOS update UI from another class/thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiviewcontroller, uiimage

I have a main "class"/view controller called "MainUI.m" that displays the UI for my app. Inside this view controller, i declared an instance of another class called "DoActivity.m" so I can call one of its methods called "getFeed" inside my MainUI. Before the method ends, it must update an image from my MainUI. And then the method repeats again. My problem is that the app crashes whenever I update the UI inside the method:

```
MainUI* mu = [[MainUI alloc] init];   

-(void)getFeed{
//some tasks here

mu.imageView.image= imageInDoActivity.image;
}
```

**EDIT**

The error says something like

```
Thread 1: Program recieved signal:'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'
```

and is highlighted on this line of code:

```
mu.imageView.image= imageInDoActivity.image;
```

**edit**

I have a MainUI property in DoActivity:

```
@property MainUI* mu;
```

But in my DoActivity constructor, i did not initialise the said property. Instead, before calling [self.doAct getFeed] in MainUI where doAct is

```
@property DoActivity* doAct;
```

I set

```
self.doAct.mu = self;
```

in MainMU so that DoActivity would know that it should update the UI of the class that called it.

How do I fix this?

Comment: provide more info plz. crash log, the method body..

Comment: What is the error message for the crash? You shouldn't be updating any UI object on any other thread. The UI can only be updated on the main thread this could be the route cause of your crash but without seeing the error we don't know.

Comment: The error says something like, "Thread 1: Program recieved signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and is highlighted on this line of code: mu.imageView.image= imageInDoActivity.image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do UI stuff on the main thread:

```
-(void)getFeed{
    //some tasks here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        mu.imageView.image= imageInDoActivity.image;
    });
}
```

I'm not sure though if this is really the cause of your crash. A crash-log would be really helpful.

Comment: The error says something like, "Thread 1: Program recieved signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and is highlighted on this line of code: mu.imageView.image= imageInDoActivity.image

Comment: @user2964075 This is most likely a zombie (Making a method call on an already dealloced object). How did you define `mu` in this context? Try making a property.

Comment: @user2964075 Your description is quite confusing. It would be much easier if you would post all the relevant information, as long as you're not developing under some kind of license that forbids it.

Comment: Okay I've solved it now. You're right about deallocation. I accidentally included an "autorelease" in my definition of the DoActivity in MainMU such as DoActivity* doAct = [[[DoActivity alloc] init] autorelease; i removed the autorelease and it worked! thanks a lot @NSAddict :)

Comment: @user2964075 Glad this solved your problem! If my answer helped you, please select it as the correct answer.